# Unable to start app built manually

Tags: macos, terminal, applications

I have create an application `APP-py3.app` stored in `/Applications`. The `APP-py3.app` contains the following files [F] and directories [D]:

- `Contents` [D]:
- `Info.plist` [F]
- `MacOS` [D]:

  - `script` [F with rights `-rwxr-xr-x` ]
- `Resources` [D]:

  - `icon.icns` [F]

**Contents of the files**:

- `Info.plist`:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://
> www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
> <plist version="1.0">
> <dict>
>     <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
>     <string>icon.icns</string>
> </dict>
> </plist>
> ```

- `script`:

> ```
> #!/usr/local/bin/python
>
> import os import subprocess
>
> executable = '/usr/local/bin/XXXX.py' arguments = [executable]
>
> os.exe
>
> cve(executable, arguments, os.environ)
> ```

The script works fine when I start it from the Terminal but when I click on the `APP-py3.app` icon on the Finder I obtain the following error: `Impossible d’ouvrir l’application « APP-py3.app », car elle est peut-être endommagée ou incomplète.` (`Unable to start the application « APP-py3.app », because it may be damaged or incomplete`) and when I try to start it from the terminal using the command `open APP-py3.app` I obtain: `The application cannot be opened because its executable is missing.`. The message seems to tell me that the executable is missing but I don't understand why OSX doesn't find the `script` executable... But maybe I misunderstand something. Do you have any idea of this trouble?

Comment: Would you edit in your gatekeeper status? It could be looking for a signed app and throwing an unhelpful error...

Comment: @bmike I authorized all download applications. Must I specify another thing?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying your script? with key: `CFBundleExecutable` value: `script`